# How can I run GAM commands from within PHP on Linux?

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to run a [GAM](https://github.com/GAM-team/GAM/wiki#introduction) (Google Apps Manager) command from within PHP on a Linux server. Trying `exec('/home/xxx/bin/gam/gam info domain')` gives return value 126 (command is found but is not executable).

I've checked that other commands run OK:  `exec('whoami')` returns

> string(6) "apache"

I've checked that user **apache** can run GAM commands from a shell:

```
$ sudo su apache
$ /home/xxx/bin/gam/gam info domain
```

> Customer ID: Cxxxxxxxxn 
> Primary Domain: xxxxxxxx.ac.th 
> Primary Domain Verified: True 
> User counts as of 2022-04-26:   Total Users: 4,591

For good measure, I've tried `shell_exec()` and `system()` and also `exec('/usr/bin/bash /home/xxx/bin/gam/gam info domain')`

For reference, I installed GAM as per [these instructions](https://github.com/GAM-team/GAM/wiki#mac-and-linux-users) by using `bash <(curl -s -S -L https://git.io/install-gam)`

Versions are PHP v7.4 RedHat v7.3